# Video File streaming not working on Safari/ iOS device in asp.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created the API in asp.net core 2.0 that returns the video file streaming Result. Below is the code sample for returning the filestream result. The URL is working fine on Chrome but the URL will not work on iOS device and Safari browser.

How to implement the range request / response in asp.net core 2.0?

```
var fileStream = await this.amazonS3Service.Open(
               request.FileName,
               path,
               cancellationToken);

return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, this.GetContentType(request.FileName));
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with video streaming. You don't explain what the problem is although one can easily guess - the stream is disposed. An HTTP response is *always* sent as a stream of data. `FileStreamResult` will read the content to return from a *stream* . If the stream is closed prematurely, for example because it went out of scope as in this case, the call will fail. Use `FileStream()` or `return File()` instead

Comment: Returning a file stream is not the same things as "streaming" when it comes to something like a video. An actual streaming server frontloads the video metadata, returns the full file size, etc. The client needs all of this info in order to properly playback the video as it's downloading. All you're doing here is acting as a proxy to the file on your AWS storage and sending each chunk to the client as you get it rather than buffering it into your server's RAM first.

Comment: You also haven't given us any information about the video itself. The ability to play a video is limited by the codecs available on the system. iOS supports only MPEG and then only certain profiles thereof.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Returning File or FileStream is not a part of asp.net core, As you are mixing of Web API and asp.net core.

Comment: As I tried to play MP4 video on Safari / iOS device, But it has shown a message "Can't play icon and message" on Safari browser. Meanwhile, the same URL is working on the Chrome browser as well as Android devices.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I found the fix.
using (var fileStream = await this.amazonS3Service.Open(request.FileName, path, cancellationToken))
                {   if (fileStream == null)
                    {
                        return new NotFoundResult();
                    }

                    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, this.GetContentType(request.FileName));
                }

Answer (score 2):

What iOS considered to be is stream range and content-length header

In dotnet Core 2.1 was added support for Ranges

Use File constructor with enableRangeProcessing

```
 return File(fileStream, this.GetContentType(request.FileName), true);
```