# The video tag does not work in the react app on iPhone, but works on the desktop

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to add a video tag to my react application. On desktop (tested in Chrome), it works fine, but not on iPhone (tested in iPhone 12).

I haven't found a solution yet

Here my code:

```
<video key={videoLink} width="100%" controls playsInline autoPlay>
    <source src={videoLink} type="video/mp4">
    </source>
</video>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried 

<video key={videoLink} width="100%" source src={videoLink} controls playsInline autoPlay>
</video>

Comment: @altho Now that I have checked it, it still does not work

Comment: I found the issue, I'm serving the video from net web app, solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61440085/17450256

Comment: I have the same issue, but my backend is express js ( Node js ).